# How do you combine a sculpt mesh with primitives for 3d printing?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, 3d-printing, sculpt, meta-objects

I created a crystal mesh 130mm x 120mm x 250mm high for 3d printing using sculpt. Now I want to add a tube within it and add some scaffold primitives to the inside of the mesh joining the tube for strength.

How do I combine the tube and cubes to the mesh to create a single entity for turning into an stl file for printing?

I know it needs a 3d print thickness and have tried adding thickness to the mesh, also getting a clean hole in the base for joining the tube to is an issue, its a saw tooth edge I have join?

Comment: Can you post some pictures to clearly demonstrate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Boolean Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) to cut out the tube from your model, and combine it with scaffolding.

That said, scaffolding is usually added when slicing the 3D finished model in your 3D printing software. I'm not sure if you will get good results if you try to do this in the modeling step.

To add thickness to a sheet-like object, you can use the [Solidify Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html).

Comment: I tried a boolean operation with the mesh and tube which didnt work. I also tried adding the modifier to add 3mm thickness to the mesh and then the boolean which didnt work. I ended up with the thickness and a jagged edge hole with the tube slotting through but the  boolean didnt work as its a non manifold shape? have I missed another step to try?